# Setup environment php 5.5.12 mysql 5.6.17

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, webserver

I am trying to setup xampp or other environment which runs php 5.5.12 and mysql 5.6.17 but i could not find this exactly versions. Do you guys know any other package or links to download?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your question is  a bit unclear. I am not sure of you are asking about xampp or php but if you need php version, you can try this link

[php release](https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.5.12.tar.gz/from/a/mirror)

Comment: Xampp comes with php and mysql built-in right so each xampp version has different php and mysql versions. What i want to accomplish is that exactly versions running in my local machine, it might be using xampp or any other package.